# Center one flex item and bottom-align another

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get one flex item to be centered vertically and horizontally.

I'd like for some text to be fixed to the bottom of the flex container.

`margin-top:auto` on the text just shoves the inner box to the top. Ideas?

```css
.container {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
.container .box {
  background: goldenrod;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

Here's the [codepen](http://codepen.io/lowbelly/pen/bwdGry).

Comment: Tried with other browsers? Centers fine here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the below instead:

```css
.box  {
    background:goldenrod;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin: auto;
  }
```

Comment: That one is a winner, thanks!

Comment: @lowbelly, just keep in mind that this solution centers the `.box` element in the *remaining space*, not the entire space, of the container. The space being occupied by the text is not factored in. Therefore, the centering is off vertically by a length equal to the height of the text element.

Answer (score 3):

Since flexbox alignment involves the distribution of free space in the container, `margin-top: auto` won't work in this case because there's no counterweight on the other side.

Therefore, one method for centering the box and bottom-aligning the text involves creating a duplicate of the text element and placing it on the opposite side of the box. This will create a counterweight.

With equal balance on both ends, flex alignment properties (including `auto` margins) can work.

In this case, even `justify-content: space-between` would work.

Of course, you'll need to apply `visibility: hidden` to the duplicate element.

```css
.container {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
.box {
  background: goldenrod;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin: auto 0;   /* or instead use justify-content: space-between on .container */
}
span:first-child {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>Text</span>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

*OR, instead of a duplicate element, use a pseudo-element.*

A less intrusive and more semantically proper method would use a pseudo-element as the duplicate. However, for this method to work, you would need to know the height of the actual element, because you would need to match it precisely.

Something like this will work to create equal balance:

```
.container::before {
    content: "";
    height: 15px; /* must match actual element's height */
}
```

```css
.container {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
.box {
  background: goldenrod;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
span {
  height: 15px;
}
.container::before {
  content: "";
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Duplicating the text is a gross hack and has SEO and accessibility implications.

Comment: @coreyward, hacks aren't ideal solutions, but they're often useful. Tables/Floats for layout. UL/OL for navigation. Duplicate elements / pseudo-elements for equal balance in a flex container. It's just an idea. The user can choose to implement or ignore.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing it.

Add `position: relative` to your `.container` CSS rule, and then use absolute positioning on `.box` to position the `span` to the bottom of the parent container.

You can center the text by allowing `.box` to have 100% width and then using `text-align: center`.

```css
.container {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.box {
  background: goldenrod;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <span>Text</span>
</div>
```